# Adding text to Array depending on If else statment Conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.net, MVC5 and C# to build a roombooking web form and then when the users submits the form, it emails a simple html e-mail to a e-mail account. That bit works fine.

The Different rooms that are bookable are just listed under each other, and a checkbox next to them.

However if more than one meeting room is selected (an overflow room might be required or catering etc) only one of the selected rooms is sent via the e-mail, not all selected rooms. I know it's doing that because the if statment doesnt add to an Array. Only issue is, I don't really understand how Arrays work so I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.

What I have got so far:

Form.cshtml View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Please select a room:</h4> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Room067)
            - 0.67 - Small boardroom, can fit up to 10 people. Includes PC, Projector and speakers. 
        </div>
       </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Room073)
            - 0.73 - Boardroom set up can fit to to 20 people. Includes PC, Projector and speakers.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Room078)
            - 0.78 - Leacture Theatre. Fixed tiered seating to accomodate 120 delegates. Room includes AV Equipment e.g. PC, Speakers, Projector and TV Monitors.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Room079)
            - 0.79 - Boardroom set up can fit up to 30 people. Can be set as a lecture room to accomodate 50 people. Includes PC, Projector and speakers.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Room166)
            - 1.66 - Small boardroom can fit up to 14 people. Includes PC, Projector and speakers.
        </div>
    </div>
```

There is a button, so when the button is clicked, the below code snippets do what they have to do and then the rest of the code I have on the page does what it needs to do.

Form.cs Model

```
public Boolean Room067 { get; set; }
public Boolean Room073 { get; set; }
public Boolean Room078 { get; set; }
public Boolean Room079 { get; set; }
public Boolean Room166 { get; set; }
public Boolean Room063 { get; set; }
public Boolean Room072 { get; set; }
```

BookingFormController.cs

```
string SelectedRoom = "";
if (model.Room063 == true)
        {
            SelectedRoom = "Room 0.63";
        }
        else if (model.Room067 == true)
        {
            SelectedRoom = "Room 0.67";
        }
        else if (model.Room072 == true)
        {
            SelectedRoom = "Room 0.72";
        }
        else if (model.Room073 == true)
        {
            SelectedRoom = "Room 0.73";
        }
        else if (model.Room078 == true)
        {
            SelectedRoom = "Room 0.78";
        }
        else if (model.Room079 == true)
        {
            SelectedRoom = "Room 0.79";
        }
        else if (model.Room166 == true)
        {
            SelectedRoom = "Room 1.66";
        }
```

What I'd like to be able to do is use the IF Else statment to see the checkbox had been selected, and if it had been selected add the room number (i.e "Room 1.66") to the SelctedRoom variable.

I know I would have to declare the "SelectedRoom" variable as a Array, but I don't know what to do after that, or if it is even possible to do.

Help? lol, if you can.

Comment: You don't *have* to use arrays here, although I suppose you *could*. The issue is in the logic being expressed in your chain of `if` conditions. As soon as one of those conditions is satisfied, that chain ends. So if any further rooms are booked, the code never checks for that. You could separate that chain into a bunch of individual `if` statements and *append* to `SelectedRoom` (with formatting as desired). You could make an `List<string>` of rooms to populate and format that at the end. You could do a lot of things, really.  But ultimately you need to check all the conditions, not just one.

Comment: As I read your code, the greater number of room selected is the one that you use as `SelectedRoom`. So you always override to the greater number of room. You could assign a numeric value to the checkboxes and just set the room to the greatest one. That however, will require either do not map to a model, or change the model. Not sure if you could allow that